# $\sup_{m>0}( \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_{m,n}) \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{m>0}f_{m,n}) ?$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\sup_{m>0}( \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_{m,n}) \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} (\sup_{m>0}f_{m,n}) $$

$$f_{m,n}:R \to [0, \infty)$$

When is the inequality true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall m,f_{m,n}\leq \sup_{m>0}f_{m,n} \rightarrow \forall m,\varliminf\limits_{n\to \infty}f_{m,n} \leq\varliminf\limits_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>0}f_{m,n} \rightarrow \sup_{m>0}(\varliminf\limits_{n\to \infty}f_{m,n}) \leq\varliminf\limits_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>0}f_{m,n}$

So I think it's true.

Comment: simpler than I thought

Comment: Thanks for the answer